# How to check whether a subdomain is redirects correctly to the specific IP address with bash?

Tags: bash, ping

I'd like to check whether a subdomain is redirects to a specific IP address or not with bash.

This is currently how I check it;

```sh
ping -c 3 subdomain.example.com
```

and I also need to check IPv6, that's how I do it right now;

```sh
ping6 -c 3 subdomain.example.com
```

But I don't know how can I automatically check this using a bash script.

I don't have to use `ping` specifically but I just need to check whether both the specific `IPv4` and `IPv6` addresses redirect correctly to my subdomain.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Please be more explicit on your *redirect* testing. Is it testing the DNS entry  `subdomain.example.com` points to a given IP address, or testing also network connectivity, or testing http/s redirections?

Comment: I'm just adding A and AAAA records through Cloudflare (with grey cloud) and I need to check whether those DNS entries took affect or not. When I run those `ping` and `ping6` commands, I can see my IP addresses pops up and that's what I need to check. If my IP addresses pops up, then we're good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then this will do what you want to test the DNS entries for your host.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
host="www.example.com"
ipv4="93.184.216.34"
ipv6="2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946"
if [[ "$(host -t A "$host" 2>/dev/null)" =~ address\ ([[:digit:].]+) ]] \
  && [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} == "$ipv4" ]] \
  && [[ "$(host -t AAAA "$host" 2>/dev/null)" =~ address\ ([[:xdigit:]:]+) ]] \
  && [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} == "$ipv6" ]]; then
  printf 'Host %s is pointing to expected ip addresses:\nIPv4: %s\nand IPv6: %s\n' "$host" "$ipv4" "$ipv6"
fi
```

Output:

```
Host www.example.com is pointing to expected ip addresses:
IPv4: 93.184.216.34
and IPv6: 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
```